# Recommended table schema for customer accounts table?

Tags: sql, database

I want to create a database schema for a system that holds customers and the charges and payments they do. What is the recommended approach so that I can later get a list of all customers with their total charges and payments using only one query?

A single query should return a result like this:

```
NAME  |  TotalCharges  |  TotalPayments
John          80              100
Nick         100               90
```

I am thinking to create two separate tables, one for the charges and one for the payments.

```
CUSTOMERS
-ID
-NAME

CHARGES
-ID
-CUSTOMER_ID
-AMOUNT

PAYMENTS
-ID
-CUSTOMER_ID
-AMOUNT
```

Another approach is to create one table for both charges and payments, using one column for each, like this:

```
CUSTOMERS
-ID
-NAME

CHARGES_AND_PAYMENTS
-ID
-CUSTOMER_ID
-CHARGE_AMOUNT
-PAYMENT_AMOUNT
```

Another approach is to use one table for both charges and payments, using a TRANSACTION_TYPE flag. 0->Payment, 1->Charge, but if I use this approach I would not be able to get total charges and payments for a customer using one query (or can I?)

```
CUSTOMERS
-ID
-NAME

CHARGES_AND_PAYMENTS
-ID
-CUSTOMER_ID
-TRANSACTION_TYPE  (Flag: 0=Payment, 1=Charge)
-AMOUNT
```

Which is the best approach?

Comment: You *can* get the desired output with the third approach in a single query. In case you also need to get a total sum (all charges minus all payments) the third approach would be the most flexible solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do a sum on the Charges and Payments table per Customer ID

```
select Customers.Name
 , Customers.id
 , ( select sum(Charges.Amount)
       from Charges
      where CustomerId = Customers.id )
 , ( select sum(Payments.Amount)
       from Payments
       where CustomerId = Customers.id )
```

Comment: Be careful with nested selects. All people will recomend avoid it. Are slooow: http://www.selikoff.net/2008/12/10/memo-avoid-nested-queries-in-mysql-at-all-costs/ .

Answer (score 1):

Your first approach is the right solution.

Sql query to retrieve data will be:

```
select 
    CUSTOMERS.ID,  CUSTOMERS.Name, 
   sum( CHARGES.AMOUNT ) as total_CHARGES_amount,
   sum( PAYMENTS.AMOUNT ) as total_PAYMENTS_amount
from
   CUSTOMERS 
  left outer join
   CHARGES on CUSTOMERS.ID = CHARGES.CUSTOMER_ID
  left outer join
   PAYMENTS on CUSTOMERS.ID = PAYMENTS.CUSTOMER_ID
group by
   CUSTOMERS.ID,  CUSTOMERS.Name
```

Answer (score 1):

In all 3 approaches, you can get data with one single query, but I will recommend the first approach as in it your data will be properly organized according to entities. And your single query will be like:

```
Select C.Name, SUM(CH.AMOUNT) AS CHARGES, SUM(P.AMOUNT) AS PAYMENTS
FROM CUSTOMERS C
LEFT JOIN CHARGES CH ON C.ID = CH.CUSTOMER_ID
LEFT JOIN PAYMENTS P ON C.ID = P.CUSTOMER_ID
WHERE C.ID = @CustomerId
GROUP BY C.Name
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use the first approach, splitting charges and payments into two separate groups.

These have different characteristics.  For instance, a payment might have method of payment, charge to apply to (which might be in a separate table to handle payments for multiple charges), whether it is a partial charge, and so on.

Charges would likely have different information, such as the billing date and so on.

As others have noted, you can combine results from multiple tables into a single query.  However, that fact is quite separate from the issue of how to design the database schema.